# Add a new NSXMLElement to an existing NSXMLDocument

Tags: objective-c, nsxml, nsxmldocument, nsxmlelement, nsxmlnode

I have following NSXMLDocument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<parent name=“abcd“>
    <content>
        <number>1234</number>
    </content>
</parent>
```

Now I would like to add another NSXMLElement directly behind the first `<number>`-entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<parent name=“abcd“>
    <content>
        <number>1234</number>
        <number>5678</number>
    </content>
</parent>
```

Just expected that I have to implement something like that, but it doesn’t work.

```
NSXMLElement *number = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@“number“];
[number setStringValue:@“5678“];

NSXMLNode *parent = [xmlDoc childAtIndex:0];
NSXMLNode *content = [parent childAtIndex:0];

[content insertChild:number atIndex:1];
```

How can I add the new node/element to the NSXMLDocument?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work"? E.g. "it doesn't compile", or "even though I added the node, it doesn't seem to actually be added..". The code works here for me, provided you do appropriate casting from the generic `NSXMLNode` to `NSXMLElement`.

Comment: Forgot the casting, thanks =) Now it works fine